# Android notification not showing up on API level 16

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to show a notification to the user in my `Android` application. I'm running two emulators at the moment. One is running at `API level 16`, and the other one is running at `API level 25`. When I send a notification to the application, the notification will only show up on the emulator which is running `API level 25`. I want to be able to show the notification on the emulator which is running `API level 16` as well.

This is my code to show the notification to the user:

```
private void basicNotification(String title, String body, String data, Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_monetization_on)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body);

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Explanation parameters:

`title` = The title of the notification.

`body` = The body of the notification.

`data` = The data of the notification (not being used yet).

`context` = This is the context which I'm using to show the notification. This context is received from a class which extends `FirebaseMessagingService`.

When I execute the code above, I won't receive any errors. The only thing which will come up is in the `logcat`. The following line will appear:

> 05-11 07:47:42.169 1606-1758/system_process D/ConnectivityService: handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=0, condition=100, published condition=100

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong right now. I used the [official documentation from Android](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) to make this method. If you need more information to solve the problem just let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after trying a few things, I found out I made a terrible mistake. The notification was showing up, but only in the drop down menu. For anyone who struggles with this, try to check your drop down menu if your notification is in there.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809420/4653908